# React Native Dynamic Component name error

Tags: react-native

I'm developing my first app with React Native and i'm stuck in a problem with dynamic component name.
I call a class named IconAccounts with two props: icon and bgColor. The props icon represent the component (a react native SVG component) that need to render inside IconAccount.
Everything should work but i have an error:

```
Invariant Violation: View config not found for name iconName
```

IconAccount :

```
import iconName from "../path/to/iconName"
someMethods(){}
render(){
        const TagName = this.props.icon
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#'+this.props.bgColor}}>
                <TagName/>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

Call of IconAccount :

```
<IconAccounts icon="iconName" bgColor="#ffffff"/>
```

icon code example (generate with svg-to-react-native-cli)

```
export default function iconName(props) {
  return (
    <Svg>
        //SvgThings
    </Svg>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try defining the `const Tagname this.props.icon` inside constructor.